# Is it linear or nonlinear, time-invariant or time-varying?

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

1. The equation of motion can be expressed as $M(t)\ddot{q}(t) + D(t)\dot{q}(t) + K(t)q(t) = f(t)$ where $q(t)$ is the defection, $M(t)$, $D(t)$, and $K(t)$ are the mass, damping, and stiffness coefficients, respectively, and f(t) is the externally applied force.
2. The equation of a lumped circuit can be expressed as $di/dt + 10 log(i) - 20 = v(t)$
   where $i$ is the current and $v(t)$ is external voltage source.

Are they linear or nonlinear, time-invariant or time-varying ? Why ?

Comment: Well, what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think they may not be the linear system since they have got the second-derivative on 1. and logarithm on 2. And both of them are time-invariant.

Not sure for my thought.

Answer (score 0):

1. EOM is a second order, linear, non-homogeneous differential equation with variable coefficients (as shown):

second derivative -> second order
linear -> t,t^2,t^3...,log(t),e^(t),sin(t),cos(t),etc. are not multiplied by q''(t), q'(t), q(t)
variable coefficients -> M(t),D(t),K(t) are functions of t 
(note: it would be nonlinear if the any coefficients were given as t,t^2,t^3...,log(t),e^(t),sin(t),cos(t),etc.)
non-homogeneous -> f(t) is not equal to zero (homogeneous if f(t)=0)

2. lumped circuit eqn is first order, linear, non-homogeneous differential equation:

di/dt -> first derivative so first order (highest order derivative in eqn)
linear -> log(i) is NOT multiplied or divided by a function of t or derivative wrt t so move it and the -20 to the other side of equal sign (it is part of the particular solution)
non-homogeneous -> even if v(t) were equal to zero (which presumably it is not), still have 10log(i)+20 making it non-homogeneous (e.g., di/dt=0 is homogeneous)

AND, both equations have t as a variable, they are variable in time, so time-varying.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX.~$ Basically, put dollar signs `($)` around mathematical expressions, and backslashes `(\)` before the names of common functions.